# Can Avenging Echo trigger multiple times per enemy?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, avenger

Avenging Echo reads:

> Any enemy that ends its turn adjacent to you or that hits or misses you takes 5 radiant damage.

If an enemy attacks the avenger and ends its turn adjacent, or if an enemy attacks the avenger multiple times, does it take damage multiple times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a creature can only take the damage once a power will have text like this: "a creature can take this damage only once per turn" (see powers like Cloudkill). Since Avenging Echo doesn't have that additional text it will trigger as many times as its condition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

It takes it twice, if it moves then missed you.

Each trigger can only happen once, however. So he could move to you (no trigger), strike at you (trigger), spend an action point for an extra action and shift sideways (no trigger), strike (trigger), then end his turn (trigger).

So spending that action point that way is either stupid or desperate.

And then your warlord buddy uses his companion strike ability and forces you to do a basic strike (trigger).